# calculate time interval of format hh.mm.ss in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date in format hh.mm.ss , now i want difference between two time of current format in hours. How can this be done.

`NSString *time1 = @"12.43.42";
 NSString *time2 = @"07.54.43";`

I want time in hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow like this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"hh.mm.ss";

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"12.43.42"];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"07.54.43"];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

int numberOfHours = secondsBetween / (60 * 60);
```

Comment: timeIntervalSinceDate is not helping . date1 is coming as 2000-01-01 02:24:43 and date2 is coming as 1999-12-31 19:13:42

Comment: you need hours, date is not your concern, it is based on timeZone

Comment: are you getting proper hour?

Comment: you must be in india that's why 5.30 is difference in date

Comment: I have added brackets, that was missing

Comment: Thanks for he help.. got it .